# How to merge two getmodels

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, custom, model

I want to merge two Model results in a variable to use it in the register. There's a way to do this?

```
  $commercial = Mage::getModel('thorleif/commercial')->load(1);
  $lcat = Mage::getModel('thorleif/mapping')->load(1);
  //$mergedresult = $commercial + $lcat
  Mage::register('commerciaux_data', $mergedresult);
```

Answer (score 1):

What data do you need from each model ?

It will be easier to make a new Magento Object or `array()` and add the details you need to that array, then register it.

Comment: I've used array_merge to get both elements.  Thank you